# In Azure API Management, is it possible to parameterise a Web Service URL?

Tags: azure-api-management

Is it possible to populate the Web Service URL based off some parameter / variable that gets sent to the Base URL?

I want to be able to forward different inbound requests to API Management to different target servers, without having to create new APIs for each new server.

[image]

Comment: Please have a look at the policies: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#example-4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify different backends with a policy.
There you can add your custom logic for different query values, params, headers,...

```xml
<policies>
    <inbound>
        <choose>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault("version") == "2013-05")">
                <set-backend-service base-url="http://contoso.com/api/8.2/" />
            </when>
            <when condition="@(context.Request.Url.Query.GetValueOrDefault("version") == "2014-03")">
                <set-backend-service base-url="http://contoso.com/api/9.1/" />
            </when>
        </choose>
        <base />
    </inbound>
    <outbound>
        <base />
    </outbound>
</policies>
```

[API Management transformation policies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-transformation-policies#example-4)